# C++ Using an enum from another class properly

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, c++14

I'm currently implementing some code using OpenGL and I've created wrappers for various OpenGL classes. In particular, I have a buffer class that can represent either a vertex array buffer or an element array buffer. To do this, I declared my class in the header like so:

```
Buffer.h

namespace FE { namespace GL {
    enum BufferType {
        ARRAY = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        ELEMENT = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
    };

    class Buffer {
    public:
        Buffer(BufferType type);
        ... rest of class ...
    };
}
```

In my Renderer class, I try to instantiate some buffers as class members:

```
Renderer.h

...
#include "../GL/Buffer.h"

namespace FE { namespace Render {
    class Renderer {
    ...
    private:
        GL::Buffer vbo(GL::BufferType::ARRAY);
        GL::Buffer element(GL::BufferType::ELEMENT);
    };    
}}
```

For some reason, attempting to use the enum this way gives me the errors "syntax error: identifier 'ELEMENT'". Intellisense also warns that "constant 'FE::GL::ELEMENT' is not a type name."

I'm not quite sure why this doesn't work, as before while testing my buffer related code I created buffers in a similar manner (by accessing the enum values with the scope operator).

Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to initialize `vbo` and `element` data members, or are you trying to create `vbo` and `element` member functions ?

Comment: I'm trying to create data members, not member functions.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at. I fixed it now by changing it to:  

`GL::Buffer vbo = GL::Buffer(GL::ARRAY);`  

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

An enum does not create a scope in C++. The type of the enum is `FE::GL::BufferType` but for using it you just type `GL::Buffer vbo(GL::ARRAY);`

If you want a scoped enum (using C++11) use an `enum class`

Comment: In C++11 and later, `GL::BufferType::ARRAY` is perfectly valid, and since this question is tagged C++14, this is not the problem.

Comment: In case it does, I have not heard about it. What has changes in C++11 and later regarding the scope of an enum? They provided the enum class for scoped enums as I already said but I dont know of anything that changed for the plain old enums.

Comment: See the [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf)(section 3.2), the [corresponding section](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum) on Bjarne's C++11 FAQ and the section 7.2/11 of the standard (in particular the example with `direction`). I have to admit it is hard to find a good quote for this in the current standard.

Comment: The correct quotes from the standard are 3.4.3/1: *"The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration."* and 5.1/12: *"A nested-name-specifier that denotes an enumeration (7.2), followed by the name of an enumerator of that enumeration, is a qualified-id that refers to the enumerator. The result is the enumerator."* (numbering are from n4296)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to default initialize member, you need to use either braces `{}` or `=`:

> Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:
>
> 2) Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration, [...]

```
namespace FE { namespace Render {
    class Renderer {
    private:
        GL::Buffer vbo{GL::BufferType::ARRAY};
        GL::Buffer element{GL::BufferType::ELEMENT};
    };    
}}
```

These restriction were included in order to avoid amibiguity between member function declaration and default member initializer, see the proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm (in particular the section **Problem 1**).